# Static variable that stores minimum number

Tags: c++, oop

I'm new to C++ so this might seem a little too easy but I can't figure it out.
I'm supposed to create a `static` member variable that stores the minimum age of any person object defined using this class.

> Do I need to write the code in the default construct or in a static member function.

Also, can someone help me with how I'm supposed to set it to the min age? Here's my code:

```
class Person
{
private:
    string name;
    int age;

public:
    static int minAge;

    Person(string name1, int age2)
    {
        name1 = name;
        age2 = age;
    }

    void setName(string n){name=n;}
    void setAge(int a){a=age;}

    string getName()const {return name;}
    int getAge()const {return age;}
};

int Person::minAge = 0;

int main()
{
    Person p1("Ash",4);
    Person p2("April",10);
    Person p3("Mai",19);

    cout << Person::minAge;
}
```

Comment: Say you create three `Person` instances with age 4, 10, 19 and then you do `p1.setAge(6)`: what do you expect `minAge` to be? 4 or 6?

Comment: The assignment `a = age;` in `setAge` is the wrong way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add following line in your `constructor`:

```
        if (age2 < minAge || minAge == 0)
        {
            minAge = age2;
        }
```

and I guess it would solve your problem.

you can also write a `static` member function with above code into it and call that function your `constructor`.

One thing I just want to highlight  - that `static` members can be called from `constructor` or any other `non-static` member functions (of course along with `static` member functions)

Comment: there is also `setAge` that can change the `age`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you got the constructor wrong. The assignments backwards, `name1 = name` should be `name = name1` (same for `age1` and in `setAge`). However, members are initialized before the body of the constructor is executed. You cannot initialize members in the body of the construtor. To initialize members you can use the member initialization list:

```
Person(string name1, int age2) : name(name1), age(age2) 
{
}
```

Next, `0` is the wrong initial value when you are looking for a minimum of positive values. Consider how you would find the minimum in a container of positive values. With initial `0` :

```
 std::vector<unsigned> v;
 /* fill some values */
 unsigned minimum = 0;
 for (const auto& x : v) {
    if ( x < minimum ) minimum = x;
 }
```

The condition will never be `true`.

You need to start with an initial value that is *bigger* than any possible input. For `int` that is:

```
 #include <limits>
 int minimum = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
```

Next you need to check if some new age is smaller than the current minimum. You have two places where a `Person`s age can change. The constructor and the setter:

```
class Person
{
private:
    string name;
    int age;
    static int minAge;    
    void check_age() const {
        if (age < minAge) minAge = age;
    }
public:

    Person(string name1, int age2) : name(name1),age(age2)
    {
        check_age();
    }

    void setAge(int a){
        age=a;
        check_age();
    }

};
```

Note that `minAge` should be `private` (add a getter but no setter), otherwise the class cannot ensure that it has the correct value. Also you should declare methods that do not modify members as `const`.

*PS*: Last but not least I realized that the task is impossible to solve with a single static member. Consider you have `Person`s of age `13`,`42` and `102`. The minimum age is `13`. Lets say the `13` year old is `peter`. Now someone calls `peter.setAge(55)` (time-travel, or whatever), then you have no way to find out that now the new correct minimum age is `42` when you only use a single static `int`.

Answer (score -1):

Have a private method called , say, updateMin that takes the age as arg and update the min if needed. Call it from contstructor and from setAge

Comment: It's actually not that obvious what this private method would need to look like. A single instance of a `Person` right now just doesn't have enough information to know if `minAge` needs to be updated or not. If the new age is smaller than `minAge`, yes, update `minAge`. If the new age is larger than `minAge`, a lot more information is required.